# Chi Square test with massive difference in sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Let's say I have a frequency table of two independent groups, structured like so:

```
Control  0.0    1.0    All
----------------------------
False    3648   2205    5853
True     33480  18132  51612
All      37128  20337  57465
```

And I want to run an A/B test to see whether the two randomly assigned populations performed a certain action.

Are these two populations so vastly different in sample size that it will mess up the math to see if there is a statistically significant relationship?

Comment: Please give the 2-way table with row and column totals. If `33480` is for Gp A, is it total in Bp A or is it count of subjects in A with 'no action'? How was it determined whether subject is in Gp A or Gp B. Random assignment? // Just tact that Gps A and B are of different sizes is not a problem. _Why_ so different may be.

Comment: Updated the frequency table, and added the margins. The two populations were just randomly assigned.

Comment: There is assumptions to the chisq regarding relative samples size between groups.  I see no problems performing the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to consider binomial proportions of `False` responses in the two groups. Is the difference in the observed proportions false (roughly $0.098$ and $0.108,$ respectively), significantly different between the two groups?

In R, this test (which uses a normal approximation) is done using the `prop.test` procedure. (I have opted not to use continuity correction on account of the large
sample sizes.) The null hypothesis that proportions are equal is strongly rejected
with P-value $0.00012 < .05 = 5\%.$

```
 prop.test(c(3648, 2205), c(37128, 20337), cor=F)
      2-sample test for equality of proportions 
      without continuity correction

data:  c(3648, 2205) out of c(37128, 20337)
X-squared = 14.851, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001163
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.01540543 -0.00493134
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.09825469 0.10842307
```

An almost-equivalent test is to consider whether a chi-squared test of homogeneity
across Groups is rejected. The appropriate $2\times 2$ table and results of the
test are shown below. Again the null hypothesis of homogeneity between the two groups is strongly rejected.

```
False = c(3648, 2205);  True = c(33480, 18132)
TBL  = rbind(False, True);  TBL
       [,1]  [,2]
False  3648  2205
True  33480 18132

chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 14.74, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001234
```

*Notes:* You can look at some of the "Related" pages (right margin) found by our robots for more details.
Alternatively, you can look at this [NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm#:%7E:text=Purpose%3A&text=Given%20a%20set%20of%20N,proportions%20is%20equal%20to%200) page on tests of binomial proportions. Another recent [related page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503599/test-for-significance-when-looking-at-2-proportions/503634#503634).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response. I use python and used `chi2_contingency()` to arrive at the second result.